# How to render a shared post's tilte and tags when shared in social platforms or other applications?

Tags: reactjs, rendering, share, client-side, react-helmet

I need to render the title of a post when it's shared via Facebook or in other apps or messages.

**I want Something like this:**

[image: properly rendered]

However, my posts show the actual title of the application, which is not what I want. When shared, I want the exact title of the posts to be dynamically displayed as per the post's meta-tags, not the main description of my application

**Do not want something like in the picture below**

[image: improper rendered]

**Using React-helmet**

To render the post's title, I am using **React-helmet async** to change the title and meta tag as client-side rendering at runtime. The changes are visible during post-inspection but not on the **page source** (Ctrl + U on the post) and social media shares.

My `index.html`

```
<title>my title</title>
  <meta
  name="description"
  content="test description"
/>
```

My code on one of the pages

```
    <Helmet>
    <title>{title}</title>
    <meta name='description' content={description} />
    </Helmet>
```

I then wrap app.js with the react-helmet as

```
  <HelmetProvider>
    <App/>
  </HelmetProvider>
```

You can replicate the issue (based on react-helmet) from this link:

https://preview-react-helmet-meta-ta.samsara-web.pages.dev/discussions/discussions-details/419

Can this issue be fixed with React-helmet?

**React-snap**
This is another package that has not been updated in the last four years.

To change the source file, it must be rendered from the server. I used react-snap to pre-render the HTML file, however, got the following issue.

```
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
19:36:10.984    You may serve it with a static server:
19:36:10.984    
19:36:10.984      yarn global add serve
19:36:10.984      serve -s build
19:36:10.984    
19:36:10.984    Find out more about deployment here:
19:36:10.985    
19:36:10.985      https://cra.link/deployment
19:36:10.985    
19:36:11.124    $ react-snap
19:36:13.427      pageerror at /: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
19:36:13.427    
19:36:13.528    ️️️  console.log at /: Buffered flag does not support the 'longtask' entry type.
19:36:13.634    ️️️  console.log at /: ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: http://localhost:45678/
19:36:13.723    ️️️⚠️  warning at /: got 403 HTTP code for https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client
19:36:13.724    ️️️  console.log at /: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
19:36:13.733    ️️️  console.log at /: An <img> element was lazyloaded with loading=lazy, but had no dimensions specified. Specifying dimensions improves performance. See https://crbug.com/954323
19:36:14.638    ️️️  console.log at /: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cloudflareinsights.com/cdn-cgi/rum' from origin 'http://localhost:45678' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
19:36:14.639    ️️️  console.log at /: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
19:36:19.024    ✅  crawled 52 out of 52 (/)
19:36:19.083    
19:36:19.107    error Command failed with exit code 1.
19:36:19.107    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
19:36:19.127    Failed: build command exited with code: 1
19:36:20.854    Failed: an internal error occurred
```

My `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "postbuild": "react-snap"
}
```

My `index.js`

```
const MyApp = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <SWRConfig
      value={{
        fetcher,
        dedupingInterval: 10000,
        onError: (error, key) => {
          if (error.status !== 403 && error.status !== 404) {
            // TODO Implement sentry integration
          }
        },
        onErrorRetry: (error, key, config, revalidate, { retryCount }) => {
          if (error.status === 404) return
          if (retryCount >= 7) return
          setTimeout(() => revalidate({ retryCount }), 5000)
        }
      }}
    >
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <App />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </SWRConfig>
  </Provider>
)

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
if (rootElement.hasChildNodes()) {
  ReactDOM.hydrate(<MyApp />, rootElement)
} else {
  ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, rootElement)
}
```

On further research, I found that server-side rendering can fix this issue. However, it is challenging to render React apps components server-side. There was a potential solution of using an Express Server with complex configurations, discussed here https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-dynamic-meta-tags-react-app-without-ssr/ .

Currently, I am using React and React-dom version 17.0.2.

One of the example posts one can use for inspection would be https://samsara.social/discussions/discussions-details/215/the-dark-triad-in-primates-mind-machiavellian-inte
or any other post on samsara.social web app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement [open-graph-tags](https://seosetups.com/blog/open-graph/) which has too many types.

```
<Helmet>
     // dynamically creating title and helmet will inject it
    <title>{title}</title>
     // og stands for open graph
    <meta property="og:title" content="Users app" />
  </Helmet>
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

For every article page your meta title and description need to be change with your article title and description so it will render it while you share article links. pass meta tags content properly from your page.