# GATEWAY_TIMEOUT deployment issues of the application built using NextJS on Vercel and Cloudflare

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, cloudflare, vercel

We made an application using ReactJS.
Everything was working fine, except that we were not able to preview pages when it was shared on a social media platform. We tried using React-Helmet and other methods, but it did not resolve any issues. It is mentioned in this StackOverflow question [How to render a shared post's tilte and tags when shared in social platforms or other applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75198228/how-to-render-a-shared-posts-tilte-and-tags-when-shared-in-social-platforms-or).

We then transitioned to NextJS, so we could SSR (server-side render) some of the pages we wanted to preview when shared on social media apps. This would also potentially help with SEO.

**Deployment success on local host using ngrok**
The transition worked functionally on a local host, and I can preview when the application is hosted via ngrok. But, I am having issues deploying it through Cloudflare and Vercel for production.

**Vercel:**
First, I attempted to deploy on Vercel. The web app was successfully deployed and is operational. One of my test pages is server-side rendered using the getServerSidePrpos() async function, and I can preview when the app is hosted on ngrok. But, when hosting the app through Vercel and I visit the page with getServerSideProps(), the following issue occurs:

[image]

**Cloudflare:**

**Method 01-**  I also attempted to deploy the app through CloudFlare and built it using "yarn build". The web app was deployed but threw a 404 Not Found error when navigating to a page that was server-side rendered.

**Method 02-**  I also tried to deploy on Cloudflare, by building it using the command "npx @cloudflare/next-on-pages --experimental-minify." But, got unlucky with this method too. The build is not complete and throws the following error:

[image]

The following `next.config` file settings were used for `Cloudflare-method 02` (only and not for other methods) deployment.

```json
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    runtime: 'experimental-edge'
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true
}
```

I used the following package versions for all my deployment methods.

```js
"node": "^17.0.0",
"next": "^13.1.6",
"react": "^18.2.0"
"yarn": "^1.22.17",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```